# Embedding tweets with ajax loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

So twitters embedded tweets work great within my wordpress site, the problem is that posts loaded via infinite scroll don't render the tweets, they just appear as blockquotes.

```
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>It’s not often I can announce that I’ve spent an exciting afternoon in a bathhouse, but I did today. A hidden Roman one. Amazing.</p>&mdash; Stephen Fry (@stephenfry) <a href="https://twitter.com/stephenfry/status/320226229569609728">April 5, 2013</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This would just render out as a blockquote unless it's loaded at the initial page load.

Is there a way to make tweets in posts loaded via ajax render properly?

Comment: Does the `widgets.js` script never load? (after infinite scrolling = never). Have you tried removing the `async` declaration and calling `twttr.widgets.load()` manually?